# Boost Asio: Calling sync read while an async_read is pending on the same socket

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, boost-asio

I am continuously reading from a socket with `async_read()`. However on some events I have to send data through the same socket synchronously and wait for an ACK (also synchronously) in an event handler other than the above mentioned `async_read`'s. I am waiting for the ACK in a synchronous `read()` call. (Please not that I am not talking about `async_read_some` and `read_some`).

Is it OK to call a sync `read()` while an `async_read()` is pending in the background?

Is it possible that `async_read()` already received half a message into its internal buffer and my sync `read()` will return with the second half?

How can I gracefully cancel/suspend `async_read()` (without any data loss), so I can safely call sync `read()` in the meantime?

Comment: You can't do anything of the above. Just re-design your application to stick with the async. approaches described in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not do that.

Quote from the boost doc:

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_read_some function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other read operations (such as async_read, the stream's async_read_some function, or any other composed operations that perform reads) until this operation completes.

As plain `boost::asio::read` is also a composed read operation this might invoke UB.

To gracefully stop your `async_read` you can call [`cancel`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload2.html)(*) nevertheless should think about your design when mixing async and normal operations. I would recommend sending the ACK from the `async_read`-callback handler.

(*)  Note that cancel has some disadvantages, described in the link. One is e.g. that `cancel might be ignored.

Comment: "To gracefully stop your async_read you have to stop your io_service" - this is incorrect. io_service has nothing to do with `async_read`, it just processes completion handlers. To "stop" `async_read` it's enough to close the socket.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I expected. It seems that there is no getting away from redesigning my operation in a proper async manner.

Comment: To gracefully stop `async_read` you should call `cancel()` on a basic_socket. Its not necessary to close the socket itself.